# Filtering an array field in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: python, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I am trying to filter the comments field of the post data from my `DocumentDB`. Here is the structure of the data

```
{
    _id: <objectidgoeshere>,
    author: {
        userId: 2,
        handleName: "VladimirPutin"
    }
    postBody: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet",
    comments: [
        {
            commentBody: "Another lorem ipsum",
            author: {
                user_id: 4,
                handleName: "JohnDoe"
            }
            replies: [
                {
                    replyBody: "Reply lorem ipsum",
                    author: {
                        user_id: 1,
                        handleName: "JaneDoe"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            commentBody: "Another lorem ipsum 2",
            author: {
                user_id: 3,
                handleName: "MarkZucc"
            }
            replies: [
                {
                    replyBody: "Reply lorem ipsum",
                    author: {
                        user_id: 4,
                        handleName: "JohnDoe"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And suppose the friend and blocked ids are in an array

`blocked_ids = [4, 5]`

`friend_ids = [2, 3]`

I would like to filter the comments so it will not return the comments of users that are blocked.

My current code looks like this

```
query = [
    {"$match": {"author.userId": {"$in": friend_ids}}},
    {"$project": {
        "postBody": 1,
        "comments": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$comments",
                "as": "comments",
                "cond": {"$nin": ["$$comments.author.user_id", blocked_ids]}
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Somehow this query returns the posts from my friends but the comments field is empty.
I also need to filter the inner array `replies`. I need to filter out the replies made by users I have blocked.